# Django: from request.GET to QuerySet

Tags: django

I know how to create a html form with Django and I know how to access the values in `request.GET`.

I know how to use the ORM: `MyModel.objects.filter(...)`

Now I a missing how get from `request.GET` to a matching `QuerySet`

I could not find this in the Django docs.

Example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

if `request.GET` contains `name=foo` I would like to have a filter like `MyModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET['name'])`.

I could code this on my own, but I think this is re-inventing the wheel. It feels too complicated to me.

Above is just one example. I prefer a solution which is more configuring than coding.

Comment: What is in the `request.GET`, how do you want to filter based on that data?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added an example

Answer (score 2):

We can here construct a `Q` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q([('{}__icontains'.format(k), v) for k, vs in request.GET.lists() for v in vs])
)
```

This will work as well given a certain key occurs *multiple* times in the querystring. Note that the fields you query over should support an [**`__icontains`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup.

Furthermore it might be unsafe to allow that, since for example a hacker could try to use `user__password` to make guesses on the (hashed) password of a user.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way

```
        filters = {}
        for param, value in request.GET.items():
            filters['{}_icontains'.format(param)] = value

        queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.items

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [django-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/)

Explained here:

> Django-filter can be used for generating interfaces similar to
>   the Django admin’s list_filter interface. It has an API very similar
>   to Django’s ModelForms. For example, if you had a Product model you
>   could have a filterset for it with the code:

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'manufacturer']
```

And then in your view you could do:

```
def product_list(request):
    filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {'filter': filter})
```

How to use django-filter in django-tables2, see [django-filter in django-table2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html)